# NFS server: some clients can't connect anymore nfsd: peername failed (err 107)

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have setup an nfs server using the ubuntu nfs-kernel-server and configured a couple of accepted IPs.
The clients had been able to connect and it worked until Friday 12th June.
One of the client, using ubuntu 18.04, still works fine. It uses the following packages:

```
$apt list|grep nfs

argonaut-fai-nfsroot/bionic 1.0-1 all
daemonfs/bionic 1.1-1build1 amd64
fai-nfsroot/bionic 5.3.6ubuntu1 all
libfile-nfslock-perl/bionic 1.27-2 all
libnfs-dev/bionic 2.0.0-1~exp1 amd64
libnfs11/bionic 2.0.0-1~exp1 amd64
libnfsidmap-dev/bionic 0.25-5.1 amd64
libnfsidmap2/bionic,now 0.25-5.1 amd64  [installed]
libyanfs-java/bionic 0.0+cvs20070825-4 all
nfs-common/bionic-updates,now 1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu5.2 amd64  [installed]
nfs-ganesha/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-ceph/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-doc/bionic 2.6.0-2 all
nfs-ganesha-gluster/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-gpfs/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-mem/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-mount-9p/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-nullfs/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-proxy/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-vfs/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-ganesha-xfs/bionic 2.6.0-2 amd64
nfs-kernel-server/bionic-updates 1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu5.2 amd64
nfs4-acl-tools/bionic 0.3.3-3 amd64
nfstrace/bionic 0.4.3.1-3 amd64
nfstrace-doc/bionic 0.4.3.1-3 all
nfswatch/bionic 4.99.11-3build2 amd64
python-nfs-ganesha/bionic 2.6.0-2 all
unionfs-fuse/bionic 1.0-1ubuntu2 amd64
```

The output of the `mount` command gives:

```
nfs.lan:/root/nfs on /mnt/nfs type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.4,fsc,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.2)
```

On my two other clients (archlinux and ubuntu 18.04), the nfs client cannot connect or mount the remote nfs directory.
The following log appears and hangs (I also tried using the same options as the working client):

```
 # mount nfs.lan:/root/nfs /mnt/nfs  -vvv                                                           
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Jun 16 15:08:45 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.2,clientaddr=192.168.1.3'
```

Server side, the only things I can notice are those logs:

```
Jun 16 15:04:09 nfs.lan kernel: nfsd: recvfrom returned errno 104
Jun 16 15:04:46 nfs.lan kernel: nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!
```

The ports seem to be still opened:

```
# telnet nfs.lan 2049
Trying 192.168.1.2...
Connected to 192.168.1.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

There are no satisfying answers in all the threads I could find using google. Any idea why these clients are not working anymore?

EDIT :

I stopped the ubuntu client, and the other one is now working. It seems the ubuntu client is the one trying to connect and provoques the nfs server logs which blocks any other connection.
No idea why though

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It works for few months and then I got the error "nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!" and all shares and mounts became not accessible until I restart nfs-server.